# Array Function On C Language

Tags: arrays, c, loops, arraylist

I try to make a function, that find the lowest number from nilaiUser,

but if I input like this :
first : 12
Second : 87
Third : 65

The output is : 65, but I expect the result is 12,

Maybe the problem is from the looping?, I try to solve this 3 since 3 days ago

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int nilaiRataRata();
    int nilaiTerkecil();
    int nilaiTerbesar();
    int totalLulus();
    int totalTidakLulus();
    
    int main(){
        int i;
        int jumlahSiswa;
    
    
    printf("Masukan Jumlah Siswa : "); scanf("%d", &jumlahSiswa);
    
        // Declare Array Size & More
        int nilaiUser[jumlahSiswa];
        int jumlahNilai = 0;
        int kecil;
    
        // Input Nilai
        for( i = 1; i <= jumlahSiswa; i++ ){
            printf("Masukan Nilai Mahasiswa Ke-%d : ", i); scanf("%d", &nilaiUser[i]);
            jumlahNilai += nilaiUser[i];
    
            kecil = nilaiTerkecil( nilaiUser[i], jumlahSiswa );
        }
    
        printf("Rata Ratanya adalah : %d\n", nilaiRataRata( jumlahNilai, jumlahSiswa ));
        printf("Kecil : %d ", kecil);
    }
    
    // Function Nilai Rata - Rata
    int nilaiRataRata( int inputRataRata , int inputJumlahMahasiswa ){
        float hasilRataRata;
    
        hasilRataRata = inputRataRata/inputJumlahMahasiswa;
        return hasilRataRata;
    }
    
    // Function Nilai Terkecil
    int nilaiTerkecil( int inputNilai, int inputJumlahMahasiswa ){
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 100;
    
        for( i = 0; i < inputJumlahMahasiswa; i++ ){
            if ( inputNilai < counter )
            {
                return counter = inputNilai;
            } else{
                return counter = counter;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I changed the function, but the error showed me that i have to make a pointer, is that right?, and how to send array to parameter?

```
int nilaiTerkecil( int inputNilai, int inputJumlahMahasiswa ){
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 100;

    for( i = 0; i < inputJumlahMahasiswa; i++ ){
        if ( inputNilai[i] < counter )
        {
            return counter = inputNilai[i];
        } else{
            return counter = counter;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that array indexes are zero-based. Meaning that an array of `jumlahSiswa` elements will have valid indexes in the range `0` to `jumlahSiswa - 1`.

Comment: Another problem is that you should declare the functions you call with the correct arguments. Otherwise the compiler will not be able to properly check for problems in the calls.

Comment: And as any text-book, tutorial or class should have taught you, you pass arrays to function by passing a pointer to the first element of the array. So e.g. `int nilaiTerkecil( int *inputNilai, int inputJumlahMahasiswa );` and call as `nilaiTerkecil( nilaiUser, jumlahSiswa )`